# Why won't jQuery's .submit() work?

Tags: jquery, forms, events, event-handling, form-submit

I'm creating a form that fires `$.ajax()` on submit. However, for whatever reason, neither `.on("submit", function(){})` or `.submit()` will respond to a form submission. Why doesn't jQuery's submit function or event work? Am I overlooking something?

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    // show/hide the $modal.
    var $modal = $(".modal"),
        $modalBody = $modal.find(".modal-body"),
        $formFinish = $(".modal-finished"),
        $button = $("#openModal");

    // Get the form.
    var $form = $("#ajax-contact"),
        formData = $form.serialize();

    $button.on("click", function() {
        $modal.fadeIn("600");
    });

    $modal.on("click", "#closeModal", function() {
        $modal.fadeOut("600");
    });

    // Get the messages div.
    var $formMessages = $("#form-messages");

    $form.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        var $submitForm = $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: wp_urls.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: submit_form,
                form: formData
            }
        });

        $submitForm.done(function(response) {
            alert("Succeed!");
            $modalBody.hide();
            $formFinish.show();
        }).fail(function(response) {
            alert("Fail!");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" id="closeModal">×</button>
        <h3>Request Pricing Information</h3>
    </div>
    <form class="modal-body form-horizontal" id="ajax-contact">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">First and Last Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="name" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="tel" name="tel">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">City</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="city">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">State</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select name="state">
                        <option value="" disabled="" class="">Select your state</option>
                        <option value="0">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="1">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="2">Arizona</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">How did you hear about us?</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea placeholder="Let us know the article, website, event, or person that led you here." name="messag"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <!-- Finished! -->
    <div class="modal-body text-center pricingSubmitted">
        <h4>Thank you. We will contact you shortly.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn" id="closeModal">Close</a>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"><span>Send<span class="pricingSending">ing</span> <i class="icon-refresh icon-spin pricingSending"></i></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submit button isn't inside the form so it won't trigger the form submit event

Change the structure so form wraps all the inner elements of modal. Then  the footer and button will be inside the form

```
<div class="modal">
   <form>
      <div class="modal-header"/>
      <div class="modal-body"/>
      <div class="modal-footer"/>  <!-- contains button -->
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `<button>` inside the form. If you put it outside the form, it won't register as submitting the form; it'll just register as clicking a regular `<button>`:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    // show/hide the $modal.
    var $modal = $(".modal"),
        $modalBody = $modal.find(".modal-body"),
        $formFinish = $(".modal-finished"),
        $button = $("#openModal");

    // Get the form.
    var $form = $("#ajax-contact"),
        formData = $form.serialize();

    $button.on("click", function() {
        $modal.fadeIn("600");
    });

    $modal.on("click", "#closeModal", function() {
        $modal.fadeOut("600");
    });

    // Get the messages div.
    var $formMessages = $("#form-messages");

    $form.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //This works now, so you'll get the following message in your console:
        console.log("Hi! I'm working now!");
        
        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        var $submitForm = $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: wp_urls.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: submit_form,
                form: formData
            }
        });

        $submitForm.done(function(response) {
            alert("Succeed!");
            $modalBody.hide();
            $formFinish.show();
        }).fail(function(response) {
            alert("Fail!");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" id="closeModal">×</button>
        <h3>Request Pricing Information</h3>
    </div>
    <form class="modal-body form-horizontal" id="ajax-contact">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">First and Last Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="name" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="tel" name="tel">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">City</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="city">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">State</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select name="state">
                        <option value="" disabled="" class="">Select your state</option>
                        <option value="0">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="1">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="2">Arizona</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">How did you hear about us?</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea placeholder="Let us know the article, website, event, or person that led you here." name="messag"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
      
        <!-- Finished! -->
        <div class="modal-body text-center pricingSubmitted">
            <h4>Thank you. We will contact you shortly.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn" id="closeModal">Close</a>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"><span>Send<span class="pricingSending">ing</span> <i class="icon-refresh icon-spin pricingSending"></i></span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `console.log()` uncovered another problem I had overlooked. Namely that the `$.ajax()` call, inside my `.submit()` function, isn't working. Would you happen to know why the done/fail functions, applied to my `$.ajax()` call, aren't working?

Comment: Hm...I have no idea why that wouldn't work since it seems to be completely fine to me. Are you sure that your request is actually finishing eventually? Usually, the "Network" tab of the JavaScript console will show you if a request has finished or if it is pending, so try looking in your "Network" tab and making sure that the request isn't indefinitely pending. If the request is indefinitely pending, then it's likely a network problem.

Comment: I tried looking at the 'Network' tab in my console. `$.ajax()` doesn't even fire, which is why it doesn't succeed or fail. Not sure why that is.

Comment: Hm...Are you getting errors in the "Console" tab of your JavaScript console? It doesn't look like you declare `submit_form` anywhere, so is that included somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your button outside of your HTML form you can use `.click()` on your button and perform the AJAX call within the click function.

Example:

`$('.btn-success').click(function() { 
    your AJAX call here  });`